# How to disable UITextField from scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I am adding UITextField to UIWebview's scrollview and on getting the uitextfield into focus , its scrolling down. How can we disable the autoscrolling property. I don't want to disable scrolling property of UIWebview.

Any help would be appreciated.